# Multiple column Tree Hierarchy (Manager, Employee) in Oracle Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, hierarchical-data, recursive-cte

I have an employees table as below :

| EMPLOYEE_ID | FIRST_NAME | LAST_NAME | EMAIL | PHONE_NUMBER | HIRE_DATE | JOB_ID | SALARY | COMMISSION_PCT | MANAGER_ID | DEPARTMENT_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 103 | Alexander | Hunold | AHUNOLD | 590.423.4567 | 38720 | IT_PROG | 9000 | - | 102 | 60 |
| 104 | Bruce | Ernst | BERNST | 590.423.4568 | 39223 | IT_PROG | 6000 | - | 103 | 60 |
| 105 | David | Austin | DAUSTIN | 590.423.4569 | 38528 | IT_PROG | 4800 | - | 103 | 60 |
| 106 | Valli | Pataballa | VPATABAL | 590.423.4560 | 38753 | IT_PROG | 4800 | - | 103 | 60 |
| 107 | Diana | Lorentz | DLORENTZ | 590.423.5567 | 39120 | IT_PROG | 4200 | - | 103 | 60 |
| 100 | Steven | King | SKING | 515.123.4567 | 37789 | AD_PRES | 24000 | - | - | 90 |
| 101 | Neena | Kochhar | NKOCHHAR | 515.123.4568 | 38616 | AD_VP | 17000 | - | 100 | 90 |
| 102 | Lex | De Haan | LDEHAAN | 515.123.4569 | 36904 | AD_VP | 17000 | - | 100 | 90 |
| 108 | Nancy | Greenberg | NGREENBE | 515.124.4569 | 37485 | FI_MGR | 12008 | - | 101 | 100 |
| 109 | Daniel | Faviet | DFAVIET | 515.124.4169 | 37484 | FI_ACCOUNT | 9000 | - | 108 | 100 |
| 110 | John | Chen | JCHEN | 515.124.4269 | 38623 | FI_ACCOUNT | 8200 | - | 108 | 100 |
| 111 | Ismael | Sciarra | ISCIARRA | 515.124.4369 | 38625 | FI_ACCOUNT | 7700 | - | 108 | 100 |
| 112 | Jose Manuel | Urman | JMURMAN | 515.124.4469 | 38783 | FI_ACCOUNT | 7800 | - | 108 | 100 |
| 113 | Luis | Popp | LPOPP | 515.124.4567 | 39423 | FI_ACCOUNT | 6900 | - | 108 | 100 |

I need a hierarchal output where each column represents the child of the parent column on the left. Here's the desired expected result output.

| Manager Id | Emp 1 | Emp 2 | Emp 3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 101 | 108 | 109 |
| 100 | 101 | 108 | 110 |
| 100 | 101 | 108 | 111 |
| 100 | 101 | 108 | 112 |
| 100 | 102 | 103 | 104 |
| 100 | 102 | 103 | 105 |
| 100 | 102 | 103 | 106 |
| 100 | 102 | 103 | 107 |

Here's the sample tree hierarchy (Manager - employee) diagram for reference.

[manager emp tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnQOw.png)

We can do it with multiple joins but is there a better way? Your help is really appreciated. Thanks!

We can do it with multiple joins but is there a better way?

```
with org_chart (
employee_id, first_name, last_name, manager_id, lvl)
as (
select employee_id, first_name, last_name, manager_id, 1 lvl
from   employees
where  manager_id is null
union  all
select  e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name,  e.manager_id, oc.lvl + 1
from   org_chart oc
join   employees e
on     e.manager_id = oc.employee_id
 )
select distinct o.manager_id, o.employee_id, o.lvl, e.employee_id as emp2
from org_chart o
left join employees e
on o.employee_id = e.manager_id
where o.manager_id is not null
order by o.manager_id;
```

Comment: Make it easy to assist you, provide sample table data and the expected result as properly formatted text (i.e. no links, no images.)

Comment: Hi - as you (I assume it was you?) tagged this question with "recursive-cte" I assume you know about recursive queries for querying hierarchical data - so you seem to already know the answer to your question?

Comment: Hi Nick, After some research I think recursive CTE could be used but I'm still not sure how to do it to get desired results, that's why I posted it here.

Comment: The old Oracle way (since 7.x if I do recall well) is with connect by prior e.employee_id = e.manager_id start with manager_id is null. Can't say whether it performs better or not.

Comment: @BogdanDincescu the only limitation I'm facing with this method is that I need to add new columns for each node, should I use case statements for that?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
with org_chart (
 employee_id, first_name, last_name, manager_id, lvl, emp2)
as (
  select employee_id, first_name, last_name, manager_id, 1 lvl, cast(null as number) emp2
  from   employees
  where  manager_id is null
  union  all
  select  e.employee_id, e.first_name, e.last_name,  e.manager_id, oc.lvl + 1, e.manager_id
  from   org_chart oc
  join   employees e on  e.manager_id = oc.employee_id
)
select *
from org_chart
```

Comment: no, this doesn't get desired result. I mean the column emp2 is coming out not as expected